# I don't understand the meaning of the word 'bevel' in this sentence

Tags: american-english

"Pamela pulled the rubber tubing tighter around Jeff’s arm, showed him which vein to hit and how to slide the hypodermic needle in with the **bevel** upward and the slender shaft parallel and lateral to the vein."

Is it supposed to mean edge? I'm not sure and would appreciate any help

Comment: Questions about the technical vocabulary of a particular field are likely to get better answers on a site devoted to that field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [bevel](https://pharmlabs.unc.edu/labs/parenterals/syringes.htm) is the part of the tip of the needle in which there is a slanted opening.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a picture of the bevel on a hypodermic needle:

[image]